# $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C_0(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis

I 'm trying to show $C_{c}(\mathbb{R}) \text { is a meager, dense subspace of } C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$. The dense part seems easy however I have no clue how to show the meager part. It seems like an application of Baire Category Theorem however I have no idea where to start. Nay help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps: Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose $f$ is a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathrm{supp}\;f \subset K$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, we can always find a function in $g \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ whose support is not contained in $K$ and such that $||f - g|| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set of continuous functions which are supported on $[-n,n]$, let's call it $\mathscr{F}_n$. Note that $\mathscr{F}_n$ is closed and has empty interior. The former is easy by intersecting kernels of point evaluations (or taking limits). To see the latter, pick any $f\in\mathscr{F}_n$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Modify $f$ slightly outside of $[-n,n]$ so that, if $g$ is this modification,  then $\|f-g\|<\varepsilon$ but $g$ is not supported in $[-n,n]$.

Now $C_c(\mathbb R)=\bigcup_n \mathscr{F}_n$, so $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is meagre.

Comment: Hi, your answer is absolutely correct. I just have one further question, that how to show $\mathscr{F}_{n} \text { is closed }$, I've been thinking about it and still can't figure out, could you please give me some hints? Thanks a lot.

Comment: FIx $n$. Suppose $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence with $f_k\in \mathscr{F}_n$ and $f_k\to f$ uniformly. Fix $x\not\in [-n,n]$. Then $|f(x)|\le |f_k(x)-f(x)|+|f_k(x)|=|f_k(x)-f(x)|$. As $f_k\to f$, the RHS tends to $0$ when $k\to\infty$, so $f(x)=0$. Then the support of $f$ is contained in $[-n,n]$.

Comment: Thanks but I have another question. Since $\boldsymbol{C}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ means all continuous functions with compact support, why $C_{c}(\mathbb{R})=\bigcup_{n} \mathscr{F}_{n}$? For example, is continuous function which support is $[1,3]$ in $\cup_{n} \mathscr{F}_{n}$?

Comment: When I said "$f$ is supported in $[-n,n]$", I meant $\text{spt}(f)\subset [-n,n]$, where $\text{spt}$ denotes the support. If $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, in particular the support is bounded, thus contained in some $[-n,n]$. Since supports are closed, $\text{spt}(f)\subset [-n,n]$, i.e. $f\in\mathscr{F}_n$.

Comment: Do I need to show the continuous part of $f$?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm starting with $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, $f$ is continuous. Also, all $f\in\mathscr{F}_n$ are continuous. Everything being considered here is continuous.

Comment: I mean for the closed part, you've shown that $\text { support of } f \text { is contained in }[-n, n]$, do you need to show that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: You know that $f$ is continuous. You're trying to show that $f\in\mathscr{F}_n$. You know that $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$. The continuity of $f$ was always given.

Comment: Why I know $f$ is continuous? Because $f_{k} \rightarrow f \text { uniformly }$?

Comment: Sure, you can argue that way, or you can use that $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is uniformly closed in $C(\mathbb R)$, which is uniformly closed in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, so you can consider continuous functions from the get go.